# Best and Worst case Complexity

Tags: java, complexity-theory, big-o

Please help me finding the complexity of following code:

```
public static int method(int[] array, int n) {
     for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
         for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            if (array[j] < array[j+1])
               for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
                    array[k] = array[k] * 2;
}
```

I need to know how BIG-O is calculated in best and worst case taking this code as an example

Comment: According to my knowledge, its O(N^2) in best case and can't find it for worst case.

Comment: [Time complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). Read. Also, the code does have an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException issue** on the second array (j), given the array is n long...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Well, technically we don't know how large the array is, though your assumption is probably correct (if `n` was the size of the array, using `array.length` instead of passing in a parameter would've been a way better implementation).

Comment: @Dukeling: that is true, this is why I added 'given' part :) (I might have read an EULA as of late... :) )

Comment: @ppeterka66 ... and that's why I added the 'your assumption' part.

Comment: Can it be different for these two cases: 1) When array is in increasing order 2) When array is in decreasing order

Comment: @Swapnil Yes, that's the difference between the best and the worst case (i.e. the `if` is always satisfied or the `if` is never satisfied, both are covered in MarounMaroun's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of questions, the best thing you can do is drawing a table. 
Let `n` be some number, and because of *worst-case* scenario, lets assume that the `if` is always satisfied:

```
  i  |  j  |  k
-----+-----+-----
  1  |  1  |  1
  1  |  1  |  2
  1  |  1  | ...
  1  |  1  |  n
  2  |  1  |  1
  2  |  1  |  2 
  2  |  1  | ...
  2  |  2  |  n
  2  |  2  |  1
  2  |  2  |  2
  2  |  2  | ...
  2  |  2  |  n
 ..  | ..  |  ..
```

If you continue doing this, you'll get an intuition about "how many times the inner loop executes depending on `n`", and you'll get that it's O(n<sup>3</sup>) - I highly recommend you to fill the table with more values in order to better understand what complexity is.

For the best scenario, you'll assume the opposite (`if` is never satisfied) so you'll get a simple nested loop, which will be O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: A table might give intuition about the complexity, though I doubt it would be sufficient for academic purposes (i.e. homework or academic papers).

Comment: @Dukeling Sure.. but this helps to better understand what's going on :)

Answer (score 2):

Best case is O(n^2) worst case is O(n^3).

The outer 2 loops execute no matter what.

The first loop runs `i` = 1 to n. It executes n times.

The second loop runs up `j` = 1 to `i`. It executes n * (n - 1) / 2 times, which makes it

O(n^2).

The third loop is behind an if sentence. So in best case scenario, it never executes and in worst case scenario it always executes. The third loop executes n times for each execution of second loop.

So O(n^3) is worst case (if evaluates to true every time).

Let's say n is 11;

First loop executes 10 times.

Second loop executes (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10) times which is 10 * 9 / 2 = 45 times.

This is 1/2 * 10^2 - 5 -> O(n^2) since the quadratic function is the biggest.

In case if always evaluates to true, the innermost loop executes:

45 & 10 times = 450 = 1/2 * 10^3 - 50 -> O(n^3), cubic factor being the largest.

Comment: could you please tell how did you reach to that answer ? Because I want to learn this thing.

Comment: added more to the post

Comment: Can it be different for these two cases: 1) When array is in increasing order     2) When array is in decreasing order

Comment: Obviously the worst case scenario is when the array in increasing order and best case scenario is when array is in decreasing order.
The average case (if evaluates to true half of the time) is still O(n ^3) since it's just worst case scenario multiplied by a constant factor of 1/2.

Answer (score 0):

O(n^2) best-case: for a reverse-sorted array; and

O(n^3) worst-case: for a sorted array.

A couple of additional notes:

Arrays in java are zero-indexed. It's generally bad practice to initialize your counters to 1, you should initialize them to 0; otherwise you risk unintentionally skipping `array[0]`.

If ever `array.length == n`, you will get 2 `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`s:

(1st) In `array[j+1]` when `j==i==n-1`

(2nd) In `array[k]` when `k==n`.

You'll get another `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if ever `array.length < n` in `array[j]`.